# How to generate an ear file from a maven-archetype-webapp artifact?

Tags: java, maven-2, web-applications, war, ear

I currently have a project built with maven-archetype-webapp artifact. The default packaging for this project is war.

Is it possible for me to insert the maven-ear-plugin in this webapp pom.xml generate an ear file that contains this project war? I tried that, but the war file doesn't get embedded in the generated ear file. It has everything except the war file.

I read many Maven related articles, and perhaps I could use maven-archetype-j2ee-simple artifact. However, I'm reluctant to this use for 2 reasons:-

- This artifact handles ejbs and all the extra features that I don't use. It makes my project looks bloated.
- Second, it seems like it requires me to install the web module into the repository first before I can create the ear file. Is this the preferred way to create an ear file?

How do I create an ear file that contains the war file using maven-ear-plugin from my webapp's pom.xml? If this way is not possible, what's the preferred way?

I'm sorry if my questions sound a little novice, I realized I have whole lot more to learn about Maven.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maven ear plugin assumes that any WAR is a separate project, so you need two projects, plus a parent project. It's a function of how maven does packaging. Each project produces one artifact. There are ways around this, but Maven will punish you for your sins. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870149/in-maven2-whats-the-simplest-way-to-build-a-war-and-the-ear-to-contain-that-war) goes into some detail on this topic.