# Set-up a Struts2 EAR Project with Maven 3

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, web-applications, struts2, maven-3

I'm migrating from `Apache Ant + Apache Ivy` to `Apache Maven` for the lifecycle management of a new project.

I've never used Maven for official releases, so I'm a total newbie on this.

Currently I have installed and configured [Maven 3](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.1.0/release-notes.html) and the [M2Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) Plugin, and I've created a new Struts2 WAR project with [The Blank Convention Archetype (struts2-archetype-convention)](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/struts-2-maven-archetypes.html#Struts2MavenArchetypes-TheBlankConventionArchetype%28struts2archetypeconvention%29), project that I'm able to deploy to [JBoss 7](https://www.jboss.org/jbossas).

After reading tons of articles and StackOverflow answers I've figured out that the *first* rule of Maven is: **one project, one artifact**;

Then, to work with an EAR I need three projects: **EAR**, **WAR**, **EJB**; but [this answer suggests that I need 4 projects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1870287/1654265), not three: one **EAR**, one **WAR**, one **EJB**, and one **PARENT**. I thought that the EJB would be the parent... so the first question is:

- which is the right way ?

And now that I've a working Struts2 WAR, the second question is:

- Which is the best (cleanest, commonly used) way to include my existing WAR in an EAR project (or in a PARENT project, if needed) ?

Creating it manually ? Generating some other *ear artifact* or *Java-EE-webapp artifacts*, and then add the dependencies ? Any example of an hypothetical POM.xml needed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to make it clear: archetypes is just a templates for projects. You can create maven project without it, all you need is `pom.xml`.

Comment: Absolutely, I'll edit to make it clear

Comment: IMO separate parent is better. You can manage all required dependencies and configurations in there and leave them out of your other projects. And you can use your EJB project somewhere else. Also see this link: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-multi-vs-inherit.

Comment: Thanks @AleksandrM for answering the first point (I've edited the question to remove the noise, while you was commenting). I'm gonna read that article now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using:

1. [JBoss Java EE 6 WebApp Archetype](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Creating+your+own+application) to generate the WebApp, composed by four projects: Parent, EAR, EJB, WAR:

   ```
   mvn archetype:generate \
           -DarchetypeArtifactId=jboss-javaee6-webapp-archetype \
           -DarchetypeGroupId=org.jboss.spec.archetypes \
           -DarchetypeVersion=7.0.2.CR2
   ```
2. [Struts2 Blank Convention Archetype](http://struts.apache.org/docs/struts-2-maven-archetypes.html#Struts2MavenArchetypes-TheBlankConventionArchetype%28struts2-archetype-convention%29) to generate the WAR:

   ```
   mvn archetype:generate -B -DgroupId=com.mycompany.mysystem \
           -DartifactId=myWebApp \
           -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.struts \
           -DarchetypeArtifactId=struts2-archetype-convention \
           -DarchetypeVersion=<CURRENT_STRUTS_VERSION> \
           -DremoteRepositories=http://struts.apache.org
   ```
3. Then I manually replaced the WAR generated by JBoss with the WAR generated by Struts2.

I guess it is the cleanest way.