# Using EJB3 And Struts 2 Together

Tags: java, netbeans, struts2, jboss, ejb-3.0

As I know, we can use ejb3 and struts 1 in Netbeans under JBoss.

But when i use ejb3 and struts 2, they got error when i deploy in JBoss 6.1.0.
I'm using Netbeans 7.2.1
I try to deploy separate components and they OK, no error.
But if I add module ejb and war to, they have problems.

Error:

```
15:48:38,023 ERROR [org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher] Dispatcher initialization failed: Unable to load configuration. - bean - vfs:/D:/javaKHANH/JavaKit_t.Khanh/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/EJB3EntityStruts2Combine.ear/lib/struts2-convention-plugin-2.3.15.3.jar/struts-plugin.xml:32:155

Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.convention.ActionConfigBuilder class:org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder - bean - vfs:/D:/javaKHANH/JavaKit_t.Khanh/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/EJB3EntityStruts2Combine.ear/lib/struts2-convention-plugin-2.3.15.3.jar/struts-plugin.xml:32:155

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.StrutsException from BaseClassLoader@162f61f{vfs:///D:/javaKHANH/JavaKit_t.Khanh/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/EJB3EntityStruts2Combine.ear}

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/struts2/StrutsException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) [:1.7.0_25]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2483) [:1.7.0_25]
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1891) [:1.7.0_25]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:235) [:2.3.15.3]


15:48:38,115 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] Error filterStart
15:48:38,116 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] Context [/Struts2War] startup failed due to previous errors
15:48:38,122 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Start: name=jboss.web.deployment:war=/Struts2War state=Create mode=Manual requiredState=Installed: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/D:/javaKHANH/JavaKit_t.Khanh/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/tmp/vfs/automount3affa1740d934a8/Struts2War.war-667258e36d105fd7/ deployment failed
```

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR: Name -> Error

```
vfs:///D:/javaKHANH/JavaKit_t.Khanh/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/EJB3EntityStruts2Combine.ear -> org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/D:/javaKHANH/JavaKit_t.Khanh/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/tmp/vfs/automount3affa1740d934a8/Struts2War.war-667258e36d105fd7/ deployment failed


DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfs:///D:/javaKHANH/JavaKit_t.Khanh/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/EJB3EntityStruts2Combine.ear" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/D:/javaKHANH/JavaKit_t.Khanh/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/tmp/vfs/automount3affa1740d934a8/Struts2War.war-667258e36d105fd7/ deployment failed
```

Comment: from what it appears - struts2 jars are missing.

Comment: i think that is not problem. This jars are existed, And problem because of this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using EJB 3.1 in an EAR with multiple Struts2 WARs deployed on JBoss EAP 6 (JBss AS 7). They works great.

If you are using Maven (if you are not, I suggest you to give it a try, instead of building complex ANT scripts that you will need to rewrite for your next project), be sure to create and deploy the project in the right way. If you are starting it now, use an **archetype**.

Since you are using Java EE and JBoss, I suggest the [`jboss-javaee6-webapp`](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-maven/jboss-maven-example-building-a-java-ee-6-application) Maven Archetype.

[I've used it too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19381412/1654265). Then use an Struts Archetype for the war, and substitute it to the one generated by the JBoss archetype, or modify it manually.

Comment: Maven, i don't understand what it is :(